# MongoDB error: DBClientCursor::init call() failed

Tags: mongodb, vagrant

> After updating my mongo client to 2.0.2 the error has changed significantly.
>
> New issue opened here: [[MongoDB connect error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980077/mongodb-connect-error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980077/mongodb-connect-error)

when I try to connect to my mongo server, running on a Vagrant VM, CentOS 6, i get this magical error shown here: http://pastium.org/view/7efba4e90f0ba228ccad377204bb9f17.

Vagrant forwards the standard mongo part to 37017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue with IP Tables so the forwarded port was getting blocked.

Comment: Its been a while but I believe I just disabled `iptables` within vagrant. The actual command I cant recall.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB's standard port is 27017.

Comment: That's unrelated - i'm using Vagrant and port forwarding 27017 to 37017.